# Jquery Modal Fade Delay

Tags: jquery, fade

I'm using jquery-reveal.js to have a pop up that fade away after clicking a link. What I would like to do now is have a delay from when the link is clicked to when the fade starts I have identified the piece of code that calls the fade but I can't get the delay to work. Where would I put the timeout in this?

```
if(options.animation == "fade") {
                modalBG.delay(options.animationspeed).fadeOut(options.animationspeed);
                modal.animate({
                    "opacity" : 0
                }, options.animationspeed, function() {
                    modal.css({'opacity' : 1, 'visibility' : 'hidden', 'top' : topMeasure});
                    unlockModal();
                });                 
            }
```

Comment: You typically call that by creating a js time. So that timer holds the timeout and then executes a lambda function which calls the stuff above.

Comment: I'm a little confused because there are 2 objects with modal name. `modalBG` and `modal`. Could you explain what they are? What object do you want to animate? This slice of code that you posted is your code, or from jquery-reveal ?

Comment: forget the question above. Could you show the line where you call reveals? Something like: $('#myModal').reveal( ...

Answer (score 0):

```
modalBG.delay(3000)
```

Would give you a 3sec delay

Answer (score 0):

In a generic way, to set a delay before any method call you can use standard JavaScript `setTimeout` method.

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $('#MyModal').fadeOut();
}, 2000);
```

The code above will execute the call of jQuery's fadeOut, with a delay of 2 seconds.

**Update**

After taking a look in the jQuery Reveal's documentation, I guess that I figured out:

```
setTimeout(function()
{
    $('#MyModal').trigger('reveal:close');
}, 2000);
```

Also, it's important to remember that the `Reveal` is a jQuery plugin, that may not work with `delay()`, since it executes another operations which may not be in the effects queue, thus, they will not be delayed.

**From jQuery API Documentation**

> It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue

And Also:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.